# Getting the Index of an Added ListView.Item

Tags: vb.net, listview

So all I am trying to do is get the index of an Item Programmatically added to a ListView from a Database.

Example:
   Index = lvwNames.Items.Add(Player)

Player is a Class that uses Get/Set methods for ID, FirstName, and, LastName.

I have googled my heart out to no avail.

***EDIT***

So I had a `GetInformation()` procedure that populated my Player Class. So I was helped by a personal friend, I just needed to pass in my ListViewItem ByRef into there and I can grab the data I needed (SUCH A DUMMY!). Still having an issue with the Index. I would like to have the newly added item selected after it is added.

Comment: if Player is an object, that code will not compile using Option Strict.  There is no `Add` overload for a `Player` object

Comment: Exactly, I have figured that out. Any Ideas?

Comment: So, is the question about adding an object, or getting the index.  Two very different things.  Just use `lvwNames.Items.Add(Player.ToString())` but you wont like the result

Comment: your funny, I mean that seriously not condescendingly. I am trying to nibble this problem to death. I have tried using the Get method for the name and adding it to a String Variable trying to hack a solution then work my way towards a more elegant solution but no matter what I try the ListView cannot convert to Integer. I tried inviting my best girl Val to the party but that wouldn't work either. Example `Index = Val(lvwPlayers.Items.Add(strName))`

Comment: This is what is called an XY problem.  You dont know how to do X, so you are asking how to hack out Y, rather than the X.  `Add` does not return an integer indicating the index (read the intellisense) and `Player.ToString()` will add the text version to the control.

Comment: Ugh, Im a freaking idiot. I need a ListViewItem, Such as `Dim lviNewItem As ListViewItem ` I'll work from there and come back with my results

Comment: Re: Edit. How does the answer **not** show how to get the index if a newly added item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Getting the Index of an Added ListView.Item` as per the title.

Method A: Look at the count

```
 lvwNames.Items.Add(Player.ToString())
 Dim ndx = lvwNames.Items.Count-1
```

Method B: Use an object

```
 Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(Player.ToString())
 lvwNames.Items.Add(lvi)
 Dim ndx = lvi.Index
```

However, `Player` is an `Object` and there is no matching `Add` overload, with `Option Strict` (which all good code should use).  The best you can do is pass it as `ToString()` as shown.

The result will be something like `WindowsApplication1.Player` unless your class overrides `ToString()`.  In no case will the ListView parse it to put the properties ("Get/Set methods") as sub items which sort of sounds like what you expect.

For that, a DatagridView would be a better choice using a `List(Of Player)`.  Each property could be mapped to its own column.